# Generating PDF from Trigger/ Future Class in Salesforce

Tags: pdf, triggers, pdf-generation, salesforce, apex-code

I have to generate a PDF of a Quote Order on Approval. So, I'll have to do it via a Trigger.

But, I can't access a VF Page from Trigger since I'm formatting the content using the VF Page and `renderas="PDF"` in Page.

So, I tried to use a future class to do the same. But, there comes another issue regarding the usage of `pagereference.getContent()` or `pagereference.getContentAsPDF()` methods : these methods are not supposed to be used in a future class.

So, can anyone suggest me some idea to generate a pdf and attach it to quote.

Answer (score 0):

For me this seems to be the easiest way to address that.

1. call into the trigger your XXPDFGenerator class adding the need record
2. create a class XXPDFGenerator
3. add generatePDF and attachPDF methods
4. generate the html into generatePDF method
5. convert to PDF and insert the attach as this sample

   ```
   Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
   attachmentPDF.parentId = record.Id;
   attachmentPDF.Name = record.Name + '.pdf';
   attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent); //This creates the PDF content
   insert attachmentPDF;
   ```

Complete info on [Cory Cowgill blog](http://corycowgill.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/generating-pdf-in-apex-trigger.html)

Comment: I use the page to render dynamically for a number of Record Types(i.e.,) the page renders in a number of ways. So, constructing the HTML in class is kind of tricky. Also, the class comes under the same Trigger context. That's why I opted for a future class. Anyway, I changed to design by adding a button to genrate PDF with a simple Javascript validation.

Comment: Btw, Blob.toPDF allows only UTF-8 characters.